# Setup Exiting With No Apparent Error on Call to .NET Method

Tags: .net-4.0, installscript, installshield-2012

I am extending an existing InstallScript project and need to call a method in an assembly that targets .NET 4.0.

The project already calls a method in another class in the same assembly: so I know that much works.

Mirroring what I see for the existing .NET method call, here is what I have so far:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// SomeFunction
//
// Wraps SomeAssembly.SomeClass.SomeMethod.
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
prototype number SomeFunction();
function number SomeFunction()
    string szDLL, szAssemblyandClassName;
    OBJECT oSomeClass;
    number nResult;
begin
    ChangeDirectory(SRCDIR); // changed from ChangeDirectory(SUPPORTDIR), which yielded error number -2147219705 in the try-catch below
    szDLL = "SomeAssembly.dll";
    szAssemblyAndClassName = "SomeAssembly.SomeClass";

    try
        SprintfBox(INFORMATION, "Debug", "Calling DotNetCoCreateObject(\"%s\", \"%s\", \"\")..."), szDLL, szAssemblyAndClassName); // FORNOW
        set oSomeClass = DotNetCoCreateObject(szDLL, szAssemblyAndClassName, "");
    catch
        SprintfBox(SEVERE, "Error", "Error %i:\n\n%s\n\n%s", Err.Number, Err.Description, Err.LastDllError);
        abort;
    endcatch;

    SprintfBox(INFORMATION, "Debug", "Calling oSomeClass.SomeMethod()..."); // FORNOW
    nResult = oSomeClass.SomeMethod();
    SprintfBox(INFORMATION, "Debug", "oSomeClass.SomeMethod() returned %i.", nResult); // FORNOW
    
    return nResult;
end;
```

When `SomeFunction()` executes in the setup I have built, I see the following output...

> Calling DotNetCoCreateObject("SomeAssembly.dll", "SomeAssembly.SomeClass", "")...
>
> Calling oSomeClass.SomeMethod()...

..., but then the setup immediately exits without any apparent error.  Getting no indication of what goes wrong makes this frustrating to troubleshoot.  Searching for a likely cause, I have found nothing so far.

Why would `oSomeClass.SomeMethod()` cause the setup to exit immediately with no apparent error?

**EDIT:**

Per @MichaelUrman's comment asking for more details about what differs between the existing class (`OrigClass`) that works and the new one (`SomeClass`) that does not:

- Both classes are `public sealed`.
- Both classes have an implicit default constructor - no explicit constructors.
- Both methods (`OrigMethod` and `SomeMethod`) are `public`.
- Neither class or method is marked with the [`ComVisible` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx); but their assembly (`SomeAssembly`) has `[assembly: ComVisible(true)]` in its `AssemblyInfo.cs`.

The differences between `Existing.rul` (that successfully integrates with `SomeAssembly.OrigClass.OrigMethod`) and `New.rul` (that does not successfully integrate with `SomeAssembly.SomeClass.SomeMethod`) are as follows (using a patch file):

```
2c2
< // OrigFunction
---
> // SomeFunction
4c4
< // Wraps SomeAssembly.OrigClass.OrigMethod.
---
> // Wraps SomeAssembly.SomeClass.SomeMethod.
6,7c6,7
< prototype number OrigFunction();
< function number OrigFunction()
---
> prototype number SomeFunction();
> function number SomeFunction()
9c9
<     OBJECT oOrigClass;
---
>     OBJECT oSomeClass;
14c14
<     szAssemblyAndClassName = "SomeAssembly.OrigClass";
---
>     szAssemblyAndClassName = "SomeAssembly.SomeClass";
18c18
<         set oOrigClass = DotNetCoCreateObject(szDLL, szAssemblyAndClassName, "");
---
>         set oSomeClass = DotNetCoCreateObject(szDLL, szAssemblyAndClassName, "");
24,26c24,26
<     SprintfBox(INFORMATION, "Debug", "Calling oOrigClass.OrigMethod()..."); // FORNOW
<     nResult = oOrigClass.OrigMethod();
<     SprintfBox(INFORMATION, "Debug", "oOrigClass.OrigMethod() returned %i.", nResult); // FORNOW
---
>     SprintfBox(INFORMATION, "Debug", "Calling oSomeClass.SomeMethod()..."); // FORNOW
>     nResult = oSomeClass.SomeMethod();
>     SprintfBox(INFORMATION, "Debug", "oSomeClass.SomeMethod() returned %i.", nResult); // FORNOW
```

`OrigFunction` and `SomeFunction` use a `try`-`catch`-`endcatch` to respectively ensure that `oOrigClass` and `oSomeClass` are set to a valid reference.  The InstallScript Language Reference's [DotNetCoCreateObject documentation](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield18helplib/mergedProjects/installshield18langref/DotNetCoCreateObject.htm) explains that "[the] function throws an exception if the object cannot be created".

Comment: Can you provide more details about what differs between the class that works and the class that doesn't? I suspect something related to `ComVisible` or `public`, as you don't appear to test that `oSomeClass` receives a valid reference.

Comment: @MichaelUrman: I updated the question with more details about the class that works and the class that doesn't. `SomeFunction` uses a `try`-`catch`-`endcatch` to ensure that `oSomeClass` is set to a valid reference.  The InstallScript Language Reference's [DotNetCoCreateObject documentation](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield18helplib/mergedProjects/installshield18langref/DotNetCoCreateObject.htm) explains that "[the] function throws an exception if the object cannot be created".

Comment: @MichaelUrman: Thanks for your input - outlining things to check that were very likely at the root of the problem. I found the cause and noted it in a self-answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to have a simple explanation.

There was a mismatch between `SomeMethod` in `oSomeClass.SomeMethod()` and the *actual name* of the .NET `SomeClass` method available to call - i.e. `oSomeClass.SomeMethod()` should have been `oSomeClass.SomeOtherMethod()`.

In my case, the mismatch was not so drastic and simply due to pluralization I initially overlooked in the defined .NET method's name - e.g. `oSomeClass.SomeStringMethod()` (singular) where `oSomeClass.SomeStringsMethod()` (plural) was in order.

That the setup immediately exited without any apparent error made it a booger to identify the simple cause of the problem.